# Angular.js Controller Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-module

I'm new to Angular and I'm going through the Intro to Angular videos from the Angular site. My code isn't working and I have no idea why not. I get the error

```
Error: ng:areq
Bad Argument
Argument 'MainController' is not a function, got undefined
```

Here's my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" ng-app>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Angular Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main ng-controller="MainController">
        <p>{{message}}</p>
    </main>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function MainController($scope) {
            $scope.message = "Controller Example";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> After angular version 1.3 global controller function declaration is disabled

You need to use modularise approach in order to make it work.

You should define angular.module first and then include angular components to it

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XmmbqM?editors=101)

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('MainController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.message = "Controller Example";
    })
```

Then change `ng-app` to use that module `ng-app="app"`

Comment: That makes sense. The Intro to Angular video is for version 1.3 I believe. Those videos should really be updated.

Answer (score 2):

Just defining the function will not be a controller. You need to use like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('MainController',MainController);
function MainController($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Controller Example";
}
```

And ensure to use myApp in your html like this:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
```

Comment: Wow, we even chose the same variable names

Comment: @DavidL which param are you talking about?

Comment: @BhojendraNepal you should have add controller name first..then the second parameter would be function

Comment: @BhojendraNepal See yourself. [Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eppNKg?editors=101)

Comment: @Tushar I was not understanding.

Answer (score 1):

```
function MainController($scope) {
  $scope.message = "Controller Example";
}
```

should be something more like

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = "Controller Example";
}
```

And then include an `ng-app="myApp"` directive in your html.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Angular Demo</title>
   <script  src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>

   <script>

    var app = angular.module("app",[])
    .controller('mainController', function($scope) {
      var vm = this;  
      vm.message = "Controller Example";
    })

    </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="mainController as vm">
    <div >
      <p>{{vm.message}}</p>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you should create a controller...

First you should create the module and controller in java script

```
// start angular module (app) definition
angular.module('myApp',[''])
 .controller('MainController', function($scope) {
 $scope.message = "Controller Example";
 });
```

Now in your HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" ng-app='myApp'>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Angular Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main ng-controller="MainController">
        <p>{{message}}</p>
    </main>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now it will start working

I suggest you to go through some tutorials first

http://campus.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js/

[https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial](http://campus.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js/)

These are some good tutorials